# How to make Form Transperent in windows c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How to make Form Transperent in windows c# ? I have a GridView in my form, which should be visible.

Comment: Sorry, WHAT do you want to do? What is the desired effect?

Comment: If i set the form opacity, All the controls in form also take effect. I dont want to do so. I want the controls to be visible and background as transparent.

Comment: I understand the issue with form Opacity and sub-controls (in which case see the answers using TransparencyKey), but perhaps you could explain more about what you're trying to achieve? Do you want an invisible form with **only** the grid showing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the "Transparancy Key" property and the "BackColor" property of the form to the same color.  You also need to make sure no other control has the same color... Especially the images...

Answer (score 1):

Opacity and Transparency Key should help you.

[Check this site](https://web.archive.org/web/20150104125228/http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial105_Transparent-forms-(form-opacity).html) for some answers.  You may want to add a panel to your form and make that transparent.

Comment: If i set the form opacity, All the controls in form also take effect. I dont want to do so. I want the controls to be visible and background as transparent.